# recorrer un array de numeros con una funcion que reciba un callback array.prototype y que devuelva true o false en javascript

Tags: javascript

la cosa esta asi.
Escribi una función llamda todos en el prototipo de Arrays,
que recibe una funcion (callback). Asumir que fn devuelve
siempre true o false.
La función todos debe devolver true si fn devuelve true
cuando la invocamos pasandole de a uno todos los elemento
del array
la funcion todos debe devolver false, si algún elemento
del array hace que fn devuelva false;
por ejemplo:

```
 **function todos(fn) { 
   // [1,2,3].todos(function(elem) {
   //return elem < 10;
   //  });
   // devuelve true
   // [1,2,3].todos(function(elem) {
   //    return elem < 2;
   //  });
   // devuelve false despues yo trato de implementar un prototype
   //para recorrer un array de tres numeros del cual retorne
   //si en el array los numeros son menores a 10 que retorne true
   //de otro modo si es o hay un elemento menor a 2 que retorne
   // false.
       Array.prototype.todos = function(elemento){
         for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
           if(this[i] < 10) return true;
       }
           if(this[i] < 2) return false;
         }
   };**
```

Comment: quieres aplicar algo como la función Some?????

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.